# Is there a way to create dot density maps with R package sf?

Tags: r, sf

That is, is there a way to place dots at random positions inside a polygon with `sf`?

It's easy enough to do with `maptools`, using [dotsinPolys](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/maptools/versions/0.8-41/topics/dotsInPolys), but since I like sf's "tidyness", I'd love to be able to make my dot density maps with it.

Comment: help(sf::st_sample)

Comment: @mdsumner that's the one I was looking for! If you turn your tip into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogous function now in sf is

```
help(sf::st_sample)
```